# Как не прерывать внешний цикл, при остановке вложенного словом break (PYTHON)

Tags: python, python-3.x

господа программисты! Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему: есть внешний цикл, который позволяет начинать игру заново при определенном условии, и есть внутренний, который отвечает за логику игры. Собственно САМА ПРОБЛЕМА: логика была простая остановить внутренний цикл while с пом. break и продолжить выполнение внешнего цикла. Но при остановке внутреннего цикла, далее не выполняются инструкции внешнего цикла, и я полностью не понимаю почему. Погуглила, в интернетах подобной проблемы не нашла, навыки гугления у меня не очень хорошие. Заранее крайне благодарна за советы бывалых джедаев. А то я только начала этот нелегкий путь становления программистом
'''

```
count = 10
continue_var = 'yes'
round = 1
while continue_var == 'yes':
    while count > 0:
        print(f'РАУНД - {round}')
        print(f'Оставшееся количество полочек - {count}')
        p1_count = int(input(f'Первый игрок введите количество палочек на {round} круге: '))
        # Проверка на достоверность введенный данных
        while p1_count < 1 or p1_count > 3:
            print("Введите значение от 1 до 3")
            p1_count = int(input('Первый игрок введите количество палочек : '))
        count -= p1_count
        # Проверка на условие конца игры
        if count <= 0:
            print('Первый игрок проиграл')
            break
        p2_count = int(input(f'Второй игрок введите количество палочек {round}  круге: '))
        # Проверка на достоверность введенный данных
        while p2_count < 1 or p2_count > 3:
            print("***Введите значение от 1 до 3***")
            p2_count = int(input('Второй игрок введите количество палочек: '))
        count -= p2_count
        # Проверка на условие конца игры
        if count <= 0:
            print('Второй игрок проиграл')
            break
        round += 1
continue_var = input('Игра окончена, желаете продолжить? введите yes, если желаете продолжить: ')
```

Comment: А что должно выполняться? Во внешнем цикле нечему выполняться, кроме внутреннего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы просто забыли перенести строку, спрашивающую о продолжении игры, внутрь внешнего цикла, и почему-то вынесли его вне цикла. Без этого внешний цикл выполнится вновь, но тогда внутренний цикл снова не сработает — потому что переменная `count` останется нулём, а условие попросту не выполнится. Это же лечится переносом `count = 10` перед внутренним циклом. Плюс ещё не объединичится число раундов, хотя это тоже предполагается.

Таким образом, получаем примерно вот такой код:

```py
continue_var = 'yes'
while continue_var == 'yes':
    count = 10
    round = 1
    while count > 0:
        print(f'РАУНД - {round}')
        print(f'Оставшееся количество полочек - {count}')
        p1_count = int(input(f'Первый игрок введите количество палочек на {round} круге: '))
        # Проверка на достоверность введенный данных
        while p1_count < 1 or p1_count > 3:
            print("Введите значение от 1 до 3")
            p1_count = int(input('Первый игрок введите количество палочек : '))
        count -= p1_count
        # Проверка на условие конца игры
        if count <= 0:
            print('Первый игрок проиграл')
            break
        p2_count = int(input(f'Второй игрок введите количество палочек {round}  круге: '))
        # Проверка на достоверность введенный данных
        while p2_count < 1 or p2_count > 3:
            print("***Введите значение от 1 до 3***")
            p2_count = int(input('Второй игрок введите количество палочек: '))
        count -= p2_count
        # Проверка на условие конца игры
        if count <= 0:
            print('Второй игрок проиграл')
            break
        round += 1
    continue_var = input('Игра окончена, желаете продолжить? введите yes, если желаете продолжить: ')
```

Comment: Крайне стыдно за мою невнимательность, спасибо вам большое <3

Comment: Бывает :) Не забудьте пометить данный ответ как верный, если он Вам помог (галочка слева от текста). Ну и ещё небольшая просьба: можно ещё на каждом ходу явно выводить, в каких пределах нужно вводить число (а то вдруг кто-то всё время вытягивал 4 палочки, а тут от 1 до 3) ;)